# PrimeFaces community edition licensing doubts

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We plan to use PrimeFaces Community Edition, in an application, which we are developing for a client. We are planning to sell this software commercially. Are we allowed?

I have read the following in the PrimeFaces user guide 5.2

**"7. Can I use PrimeFaces in a commercial software?
Yes, Apache V2 License is a commercial friendly library. PrimeFaces does not bundle any third
party software that conflicts with Apache. Same goes for Elite Releases for ELITE and PRO users."**

I am guessing that this allows us to use PrimeFaces in our application, but, I just want to be sure before we use this in our application. I would appreciate if someone can advise me on the same.

Regards

Sachin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're no better at being lawyers than you are.

Comment: Read the first word of the answer. And detailed info is on dozen sites about Apache license. I voted to close to

Answer (score 0):

The differents from versione are [these](http://primefaces.org/support.html)

The answer of your question is written in your question:

> Can I use PrimeFaces (Community) in a commercial software? **Yes**